# How to extract texts between <p> tags

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I want to extract texts from HTML page(s) which placed in `p` and `li` tags, so I can start to tokenize the page to construct inverted index(es) for each page in order to answer search queries.

How I can get `p` tags using jsoup

```
Elements e = doc.select("");
```

What could be the string to be written in that parameter?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This can do the job

```
Elements e=doc.select("p");
```

Here is a list of all [selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) you can use.

Suppose you have this html:

```
String html="<p>some <strong>bold</strong> text</p>";
```

To get `some bold text` as result you should use:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element p= doc.select("p").first();
String text = doc.body().text(); //some bold text
```

or

```
String text = p.text(); //some bold text
```

Suppose now you have the following complex html

```
String html="<div id=someid><p>some text</p><span>some other text</span><p> another p tag</p></div>"
```

To get the values from the two `p` tags you have to do something like this

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element content = doc.getElementById("someid");
Elements p= content.getElementsByTag("p");

String pConcatenated="";
for (Element x: p) {
  pConcatenated+= x.text();
}

System.out.println(pConcatenated);//sometext another p tag
```

You can find more info [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation) also

Hope this helped

Comment: Yeah i know it gets the p tags from the cookbook,but with complex structures like <p><br> or <p class... etc it doesnt work for them.For all html writing structure,it must produce same result.How can i do that?

Comment: Note: when using `select.("p").first();` it will return the second element if the first element is empty e.g. for  `<p> </p><p>test</p>`, the function will return "test" rather than " ". I had to use getElementsByTag to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String testText1 = d.select("body").text();
System.out.println(testText);
```

or

```
String testText2 = d.select("body p").text();
System.out.println(testText);
```

You can use this for getting the text from tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File input = new File("/home/s5/Downloads/PDFCopy/PDs.html");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8","http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/wireless/aironet-1815-series-access-points/datasheet-c78-738481.pdf");
        Elements link = doc.select("p");
        String linkText = link.text();
        //System.out.println(linkText);
        String[] words=linkText.split("\\W");
        for(String str:words) 
        {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```