# JSOUP Title of a link extraction?

Tags: java, parsing, web, jsoup, screen-scraping

im using Java and Jsoup and the portion of HTML I'm trying to utilize is

```
<i class="fa fa-star"></i> <a href="#taskruns" data-toggle="tab">396900 runs submitted</a>
```

I just need to extract the title "396900 runs"

How would I go about doing this? I'm fairly new to parsing and web scraping

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract texts between <p> tags using jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713206/how-to-extract-texts-between-p-tags-using-jsoup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how can you exact text from html.

```
import java.io.IOException;  
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;  
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;  
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class WebScraping{  
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException{  
            String html = "<i class='fa fa-star'></i> <a href='#taskruns' data-toggle='tab'>396900 runs submitted</a>";


            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html); //First you have to parse html 
            Element link = doc.select("a").first(); //Then find the css selector from which you want to extract data

            String linkText = link.text(); //Then extract the text from selector

            System.out.println(linkText);
    }  
}
```

You can learn more from [here](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html).