# wrap content before, between and after a tagName inside Element

Tags: java, jsoup

Cosidering this:

```
Element el = Jsoup.parse("<div>text <i>italic</i> <hr> <b>bold</b> <hr> text2 </div>");
```

How can I wrap in div only :
`text <i>italic</i>` then `<b>bold</b>` then `text2`

To obtain :

```
<div>
   <div> text <i>italic</i>  </div>
   <hr>
   <div><b>bold</b>  </div>
   <hr>
   <div> text2  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713206/how-to-extract-texts-between-p-tags check this answer i think its helpfull for you

Comment: thank but I think this is not related !